# How is the use response of callout mediator in jms proxy?

Tags: wso2, jms, wso2-esb

I have the Jms Proxy in which i use the callout mediator. How is in the callout mediator get a response?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="JmsQueue" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
  transports="jms" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
      <callout action="http://LoadTestSrv/IService1/ConfirmPayment" endpointKey="LoadTestSrvEp">
        <source type="envelope"/>
        <target key="response"/>
      </callout>
      <log level="full">
        <property expression="get-property('response')" name="Response"/>
      </log>      
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence />
    <faultSequence>
      <log category="ERROR" level="custom">
        <property name="Proxy 'JmsQueue'" value="********* FAULT *********"/>
      </log>
      <property name="SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
      <log level="custom">
        <property name="Transaction Action" value="Rollbacked"/>
      </log>
    </faultSequence>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Your proxy seems right, what is your problem ?

Comment: I don't see response in log (Response = null)

Comment: The problem decided putting the "OUT_ONLY" after <callout/>